# Getting tag number of a field in google protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

How to get the tag number of a particular field from a protobuf object after compiling into a C++ class?

Consider the below example protobuf message and I had compiled this message to get the corresponding C++ header for *Person* class

File: *person.proto*

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

In my C++ code

```
Person *foo = new Person();
foo->set_id(123);
foo->set_name("bar");
foo->set_email("baz@qux.com");
```

Now I want to get the tag number of each field in the person message like the below one

```
int tag_id = foo->some_method_to_get_tag_number_of_id(); \\tag number of id is 1
int tag_name = foo->some_method_to_get_tag_number_of_name(); \\tag number is 2
int tag_email = foo->some_method_to_get_tag_number_of_email(); \\tag number is 3
```

Is it possible to get the tag number, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`Descriptor`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#Descriptor). For example (untested, just to get the idea):

```
Person::descriptor()->FindFieldByName("id")->number()
```